# Two-level multisites in WordPress

Tags: multisite

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement something like sub-multisites, like parent-child multisite relation.

So, what i want is a way to have something like this:

```
/site1
/site1/subsite1
/site1/subsite2
/site2
```

etc...

My approach has been use mod-rewrite to change from /site1-subsite1 to /site1/subsite1 meaning that I'm aware of the permanlinks changes, etc...

I will like to know if there is a more cleaner way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

I believe the domain mapping plugin can do this, but don't quote me on that.

Domain mapping isn't necessarily limited to mapping to other domains. It can map to subdirectories too.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use: [Networks PLUS](http://wpebooks.com/networks/)

> *Have you ever wanted the ability to assign a child site to a child site? Now you can using Networks +. This plugin provides the interface to set up another network of sites within the install you already have. You may choose to run this additional network off a different domain entirely or a subdomain – it’s very flexible.*